# Select entities where referenced objects property is equals value

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, query-builder

Right now i try to wrap my head around Doctrine2.

So i have the following structure:

I have an article entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @ORM\Table(name="article")
 */
class Article extends BaseEntity {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ArticleRevision", mappedBy="article", cascade={"persist"})
     * @var ArrayCollection
     */
    private $articleRevisions;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ArticleRevision")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="currentRevisionId", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     * @var ArticleRevision
     */
    private $currentRevision;

    public function __construct(array $options = null) {
        $this->articleRevisions = new ArrayCollection();
        parent::__construct($options);
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }
    /**
     * @param int $id
     */
    public function setId($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @param ArticleRevision $articleRevision
     */
    public function addArticleRevision($articleRevision) {
        $this->articleRevisions[] = $articleRevision;
        $articleRevision->setArticle($this);
    }

    /**
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getArticleRevisions() {
        return $this->articleRevisions;
    }

    /**
     * @return ArticleRevision
     */
    public function getCurrentRevision() {
        return $this->currentRevision;
    }
    /**
     * @param ArticleRevision $articleRevision
     */
    public function setCurrentRevision($articleRevision) {
        $this->currentRevision = $articleRevision;
    }
}
```

that has articleRevisions and references its current revision:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @ORM\Table(name="articlerevision")
 */
class ArticleRevision extends BaseEntity {

    const TYPE_RELEASE = "release";
    const TYPE_DRAFT = "draft";
    const TYPE_AUTOSAVE = "autosave";

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @var int
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="categoryId", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @var Category
     **/
    private $category;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Article", inversedBy="articleRevisions")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="articleId", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @var Article
     **/
    private $article;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @var string
     */
    protected $urlParam;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @var string
     */
    protected $copyright;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @var string
     */
    protected $supertitle;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @var string
     */
    protected $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     * @var string
     */
    protected $teaser;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     * @var string
     */
    protected $text;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ArticleRevision")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="previousRevisionId", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     * @var ArticleRevision
     */
    private $previousRevision;

    public function __construct(array $options = null) {
        parent::__construct($options);
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }
    /**
     * @param int $id
     */
    public function setId($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @return Category
     */
    public function getCategory() {
        return $this->category;
    }
    /**
     * @param Category $category
     */
    public function setCategory($category){
        $this->category = $category;
    }

    /**
     * @return Article
     */
    public function getArticle() {
        return $this->article;
    }
    /**
     * @param Article $article
     */
    public function setArticle($article) {
        $this->article = $article;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCopyright() {
        return $this->copyright;
    }
    /**
     * @param string $copyright
     */
    public function setCopyright($copyright) {
        $this->copyright = $copyright;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUrlParam() {
        return $this->urlParam;
    }
    /**
     * @param string $urlParam
     */
    public function setUrlParam($urlParam) {
        $this->urlParam = $urlParam;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSupertitle() {
        return $this->supertitle;
    }
    /**
     * @param string $supertitle
     */
    public function setSupertitle($supertitle) {
        $this->supertitle = $supertitle;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitle() {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $title
     */
    public function setTitle($title) {
        $this->title = $title;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTeaser() {
        return $this->teaser;
    }
    /**
     * @param string $teaser
     */
    public function setTeaser($teaser) {
        $this->teaser = $teaser;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getText() {
        return $this->text;
    }
    /**
     * @param string $text
     */
    public function setText($text) {
        $this->text = $text;
    }

    /**
     * @return ArticleRevision
     */
    public function getPreviousRevision() {
        return $this->previousRevision;
    }
    /**
     * @param ArticleRevision $previousRevision
     */
    public function setPreviousRevision($previousRevision) {
        $this->previousRevision = $previousRevision;
    }
}
```

What i am trying to achieve is to select every article, where the categoryId of the currentRevision is for example 1.

I've tried:

```
$qb = $this->getRepository()->createQueryBuilder('a');
$qb->leftJoin('a.currentRevision', 'r')
   ->where('r.category = :category')
   ->setParameters(array('category' => $category));
return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Where `$category` is an int or the `Application\Entity\Category`. Both is returning an empty array. Can you point me in the right direction?

Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT**

Ouput of `$qb->__toString()`:

> SELECT a FROM Application\Entity\Article a LEFT JOIN a.currentRevision
>   r WHERE r.category = :category

Answer (score 3, accepted):

r.category = :category, reference to Entity Category not to scalar field, you should join also Category and change condition to something like that:

```
$qb = $this->getRepository()->createQueryBuilder('a');
$qb->leftJoin('a.currentRevision', 'r')
   ->leftJoin('r.category', 'c')
   ->where('c.id = :category')
   ->setParameters(array('category' => $category));
return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```